# How to iterate through a list of strings generated from a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that will state True if a sms message has links and False if a sms message doesn’t have links. I am using a csv file which first was imported as a list of lists. I converted it to a list of strings because I wanted to convert each string into a list so that I could iterate over the words in each string until I got to a word beginning with 'http'. The output I get is just a single value False, so I think that this code is not iterating through each message in the list of strings.

```
import csv


def read_csv():
    messages = []
    with open('spam.csv', newline='', encoding='latin-1') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in spamreader:
            string_row = str(row[1])
            messages.append(string_row)
   for string in messages)
    csvfile.close()
    return messages


def has_links(messages):
    txt_messages = messages
    values = []
    for message in txt_messages:
        sing_words = list(message)
        message_value = False
        for word in sing_words
            if word == 'http':
                message_value = True
                values.append(message_value)
            else:
                message_value = False
                values.append(message_value)
        return message_value


def main():
    messages = read_csv()
    print(has_links(messages))
main()



It returns a single value (False), not the list of values computed by has_links().
```

Comment: I don't think your implementation is correct. If you're reading words, you should minimally use `str.split(' ')` somewhere. I think you could be iterating by the character instead with your current implementation

Comment: I would also suggest you to use Regex to find links. Merely looking for `http` will not work for all links

Comment: @KatKatz try using a python debugging ide like pycharm. Then step though your code. I think you will be surprised with what your results actually are from what you are expecting. It will really help you in the long run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're using return message_value at your 1st iteration itself and therefore,   it returns only 1 value and comes out of the method.
2. I'm not sure if you intended to use yield.
3. Also, I think the logic is flawed.
4. sing_words = list(message) would just separate each characters and
   you would be looping over individual characters. So you'll always get False.

Code:

```
def has_links(messages):
    txt_messages = messages
    values = []
    for message in txt_messages:
        message_value = False
        if 'http://' in message:
            message_value = True
            values.append(message_value)
        else:
            message_value = False
            values.append(message_value)
    return values
```

OR

```
def has_links_v2(messages):
    txt_messages = messages
    for message in txt_messages:
        if 'http://' in message:
            yield True
        else:
            yield False
```